# How to invoke MBeans from command prompt in Wildfly 8.2.0

Tags: jmx, wildfly-8, mbeans, twiddle

I have below queries.

1. Is there any way to access JBoss MBeans in EAP 6 (`wildfly 8.2.0`) through Command Line like `twiddle` in EAP 5 (`JBoss 6 AS`) ?
2. Whether JBoss EAP 6 has any command line tool (like twiddle.sh) to invoke custom MBeans ?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Domain mbeans are out of the jbosscli scope at the moment, so it seems from this jboss issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PRODMGT-425